# utilizing awk and making an awk script - beginner question

Tags: bash, awk

- input fields are this order: **lastname, firstname, section, assignment, grade.**
- with a list of grades from the input file grades.txt, make an awk script
  which prints to match the format below.
- print the avg grade and the number of failing grades (<= 60) in the specified section.

grades.txt:

```
Alicia, Joseph, 2, 1, 40
Alfonzo, Gary, 3, 3, 85
Albert, Tom, 2, 1, 90
Bailey, Linda, 3, 2, 76
Butcher, Stewie, 3, 1, 80
Buser, Gary, 1, 3, 59
Canyon, Nicole, 2, 5, 90
```

**EXAMPLE OUTPUT for section 1 (for
the section number specified on the cmd-line)**

```
Gary Buser – 59 – 3
Fails = 1
Average Grade = 59
```

```
BEGIN {
    # first last - grade - assignment
    # Fails     = 1
    # Avg Grade = grade
      }
      {
    for(i=0; i<=NF; i++)
    print($2, $1, $5, "-", $4);
    total+=$5;
    if ( $5 <= 60 )
        fails=fails++;
    else {
        fails=0;
        }
    avg=total/i;
    }
END {
   print("Fails        =", fails);
   print("Average Grade =", avg);
    }
```

The command line I'm trying to use but it is not working:

```sh
awk '$3==1' -f name.awk grades.txt
```

What am I doing wrong to achieve the desired output?

Comment: Please don't use irrelevant language tags (to broaden the audience or whatever reason).

Comment: I don't fully understand which awk command i should be utilizing. I know you have to specify which "section" of students to grab but that is it

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*" }
$3 == sect {
    print $2, $1, "-", $5, "-", $4
    if ( $5 <= 60 ) {
        fails++
    }
    sum += $5
    cnt++
}
END {
    print "Fails =", fails+0
    print "Average Grade =", (cnt ? sum / cnt : 0)
}
```

```
$ awk -v sect=1 -f tst.awk grades.txt
Gary Busey - 43 - 3
Fails = 1
Average Grade = 43
```

Comment: Excellent, one further question how is (cnt ? sum / cnt : 0) translated to english ?

Comment: That's just a ternary expression as seen in many programming languages where the statement `<condition> ? <expression 1> : <expression 2>` means `if <condition> then <expression 1> else <expression 2>` so in this case it tests for cnt being non-zero and if so divides sum by cnt otherwise prints 0. I'm using that test to protect against a divide-by-zero error if there were no entries for a given `sect` in your input. See [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:).